# How to create an array of unique elements from a string/array in bash?

Tags: string, array, uniq, patterns

If I have a string "1 2 3 2 1" - or an array [1,2,3,2,1] - how can I select the unique values, i.e.

```
"1 2 3 2 1" produces "1 2 3"
```

or

```
[1,2,3,2,1] produces [1,2,3]
```

Similar to uniq but uniq seems to work on whole lines, not patterns within a line...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With GNU `awk` (this also retains original order)

```
printf '%s\n' "1 2 3 2 1" | awk -v RS='[[:space:]]+' '!a[$0]++{printf "%s%s", $0, RT}'
1 2 3
```

To `read` into a `bash` array

```
read -ra arr<<<$(printf '%s\n' "1 2 3 2 1" |
 awk -v RS='[[:space:]]+' '!a[$0]++{printf "%s%s", $0, RT}')
printf "%s\n"  "${arr[@]}"
1
2
3
```

Comment: How can I then make that an array ?

Comment: @MichaelDurrant, if you mean a `bash` array, added a way

Comment: See [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/167194/143394) if your array contains whitespace

Comment: @iruvar can you please explain what actually this means? i'm new to awk scripting and it would be helpful if you can clarify what actually happens when you say this    !a[$0]++

Comment: @iruvar if not possible to explain in comments any website explaining the above syntax at least would be beneficial.

Comment: @Abhishek, please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11532197/753731) answer and the accompanying comments

Comment: @Abhishek, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1444448/753731) explanation is more detailed

Answer (score 12):

If you are using zsh:

```
$ array=(1 2 3 2 1)
$ echo ${(u)array[@]}
1 2 3
```

or (if `KSH_ARRAYS` option is not set) even

```
$ echo ${(u)array}
1 2 3
```

Comment: If the array may contain empty elements, you should use `"${(u)array[@]}"` or `"${(@u)array}"` instead (note the quotes).

Comment: I am using _zsh 5.1.1 (x86_64-ubuntu-linux-gnu)_, and `${(u)array}` works even if the array is empty or contains an empty string, without quotes.

Answer (score 5):

For an array with arbitrary values, it's quite tricky with `bash` as it doesn't have a builtin operator for that.

`bash` however happens not to support storing NUL characters in its variables, so you can make use of that to pass that to other commands:

The equivalent of `zsh`'s:

```
new_array=("${(@u}array}")
```

on a recent GNU system, could be:

```
eval "new_array=($(
  printf "%s\0" "${array[@]}" |
    LC_ALL=C sort -zu |
    xargs -r0 bash -c 'printf "%q\n" "$@"' sh
  ))"
```

Alternatively, with recent versions of `bash`, and assuming none of the array elements are empty, you could use associative arrays:

```
unset hash
typeset -A hash
for i in "${array[@]}"; do
  hash[$i]=
done
new_array=("${!hash[@]}")
```

With bash 4.4 and newer and with GNU `sort`:

```
readarray -td '' new_array < <(
  printf '%s\0' "${array[@]}" | LC_ALL=C sort -zu)
```

The order of the elements would not be the same in those different solutions.

With `tcsh`:

```
set -f new_array = ($array:q)
```

Would retain the **f**irst element (`a b a` => `a b`) like `zsh`'s `(u)` expansion flag.

```
set -l new_array = ($array:q)
```

Would retain the last (`a b a` => `b a`). Those however remove empty elements from the array.

Answer (score 1):

This solution worked for me.

```
ids=(1 2 3 2 1)
echo "${ids[@]}" | tr ' ' '\n' | sort -u | tr '\n' ' '
```

The above produces 1 2 3 as the output.

Shorter version as suggested by Costas could be,

```
printf "%s\n" "${ids[@]}" | sort -u | tr '\n' ' '
```

To store the end results to an array, you could do something like,

```
IFS=$' '
arr=($(printf "%s\n" "${ids[@]}" | sort -u | tr '\n' ' '))
unset IFS
```

Now, when I do an echo on `arr`, this is the output I get.

```
echo "${arr[@]}"
1 2 3
```

**References**

https://stackoverflow.com/a/13648438/1742825
https://stackoverflow.com/a/9449633/1742825

Comment: @Costas, thanks. I have incorporated it to the answer.

Comment: How can I make the end result be an array?

Comment: @MichaelDurrant, please see the updated answer and let me know if this is fine.

Comment: If you wants to put result into array you can strip last command `tr '\n' ' '`

Answer (score 0):

To do it entirely in the shell and put the result in an array,

```
declare -A seen
for word in one two three two one
do
        if [ ! "${seen[$word]}" ]
        then
                result+=("$word")
                seen[$word]=1
        fi
done
echo "${result[@]}"
```

In words: if we haven’t seen a given word yet,
add it to the `result` array and flag it as having been seen. 
Once a word has been seen, ignore subsequent appearances of it.

Comment: Note that you need `unset seen` before `declare -A seen` in case `$seen` was previously defined (even as a scalar variable from the environment).